# How to find rolling x-day sum with partition in Presto/SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I'm looking for appropriate SQL syntax to accomplish something like this:

```
SUM(T.revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY T.date BETWEEN
        DATEADD(T.date, -15) AND DATEADD(T.date, 15) AS rolling_30_day_revenue
)
FROM tab T
```

The end results should be a rolling 30-day summation of revenue. What is the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions with a range-based frame:

```sql
SELECT sum(t.revenue) OVER (
    ORDER BY t.date
    RANGE BETWEEN interval '15' day PRECEDING AND interval '15' day FOLLOWING)
FROM tab t
```

For each row, the frame will include all rows that fall in the window starting 15 days before the row's `t.date` and 15 days after the row's `t.date`.

See [Full support for frame type RANGE](https://trino.io/blog/2021/03/10/introducing-new-window-features.html#-full-support-for-frame-type-range)
 for more details.

Comment: `days` could be replaced with any preferred name, right? (eg it doesn't play any syntax-specific role)

Comment: Also, if I needed to add a group by clause, could I simply add it below the `RANGE ...` line? (GROUP BY account_id)

Comment: Yes, you can put any valid value of INTERVAL type. `interval '15' day` is just the syntax for an interval representing 15 days. You could also do `interval '2' month`, for instance, or if you're dealing with a `timestamp` column, an interval representing hours/minutes/seconds, such as `interval '10' hour`.